# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() while updating Database

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

I know this error comes when in Async Task, we try to update UI in doInBackGround...

But i am not able to get it where i am doing it.

I am in between of a very large and stable as of now code...

```
SaveThread saveThread = new SaveThread(....);
    Thread thread = new Thread(saveThread);
    thread.start();

class SaveThread implements Runnable {
    ...........


    ...........
    @Override
    public void run() {


                        list = saveMultiple(mContext, array);
                    }


    }
}
```

inside API saveMultiple(context, array)

```
{
 Places placeItem = new Places().InitFromJsonObject(context,item);
}
```

inside API InitFromJsonObject(context,item);

```
{
 new Offers(context, offer);
}
```

inside API offers(context, offer) ----> API save(context) ---->

inside save API

```
    {
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Long now = Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

            if(context != null){
                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, OFFER_ID + "=?", new String[]{offer_id}, null);
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

                contentValues.put(OFFER_ID, offer_id);

                int count = cursor.getCount();
                if (count == 0) {
                    contentValues.put(CREATED_AT, now);
                    contentValues.put(UPDATED_AT, now);
                    context.getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                } else {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    contentValues.put(UPDATED_AT, now);
                    context.getContentResolver().update(CONTENT_URI, contentValues, OFFER_ID + "=?", new String[]{offer_id});
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }.execute();
}

}


Error Logs are 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.y2cf.hoppr.dao.provider.models.Offers.save(Offers.java:118)
at com.y2cf.hoppr.dao.provider.models.Offers.save(Offers.java:113)
at com.y2cf.hoppr.dao.provider.models.Offers.<init>(Offers.java:90)
at com.y2cf.hoppr.dao.provider.models.Places.InitFromJsonObject(Places.java:528)
at com.y2cf.hoppr.dao.provider.models.Places.saveMultiple(Places.java:785)
at com.y2cf.hoppr.dao.provider.models.Places$SaveThread.run(Places.java:1571) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not     called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
```

... 7 more

It is giving this error while executing async task but i think i am not updating any UI while updating content values..

I know its a bad coding as we are starting async task inside java native thread...but why this error is coming??

Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You have to create that inner AsyncTask in the UIThread.